# How do i install from USB disk?

Tags: installation, wubi, 64-bit

I've tried booting from my usb flash drive even after creating a bootable USB disk and several attempts to alter my bios into booting from the usb proved futile.

Also, when I tried the assisted installer in the ubuntu disk I still couldn't get it to work usual reply is `C:\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr not found` error.

I use a samsung np300e5c laptop.

What do i do?

Comment: Which OS are you using (i.e. Windows, Linux or something different)? With Linux it would be useful to know which distribution (Ubuntu, openSuSE, ...).

Comment: I use a windows 8 OS 64 bit and i just tried the unetbooting and got the same reply of \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr not found error.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to any other linux distro at the time, you can install `unetbootin` and with that great tool you can make bootable usb disk from any linux image file. also there is a tool in ubuntu called `startup disk creator`. it does the same functionality, but `unetbootin` is the one I recom ;) in ubuntu you can install it by `apt-get` ;)

Comment: plus, make sure that your image file has been correctly downloaded. you can do it by md5 comparation ;)

Comment: I'm still getting the same reply

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to another Linux machine, you can even dd the iso onto your flash drive. For example, if your usb stick shows up as /dev/sdb:

```
sudo dd if=/Downloads/mini.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

On Windows, I prefer [Image Writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/). I know both of these methods work on most machines.

But let us know.. What exact computer are you using?

Comment: I'm using a windows 8 computer

Comment: Is there an option to disable _EFI_ or _SecureBoot_ in your BIOS? [More here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Answer (score 0):

I never used Windows 8, so I am out of here. But a little bit of google resulted in this [tool](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) which seems to work with windows8, too.